# how to find column header and return column number vba

Tags: excel, vba

i am looking for a specific column header in the first row of a sheet called "Reference" and wrote this:

```
colnum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Reference", 1:1,0)
```

however, it is saying there is something wrong with my syntax. I am not sure what is wrong. Can someone correct this so that it returns the correct column number when it finds the header "Reference" in row one of my sheet.

Comment: Change `1:1` to `Worksheets("Reference").Range("1:1")`.

Comment: `Range.Find` also works nicely here and gives your access to other properties of the target cell. Depends on use case of course

Comment: Hey there @BigBen. Why there is `Worksheets("Reference").Range("1:1")` in your proposed code and not `Worksheets("Reference").Range("A1")` ?? What `Range("1:1")` means??

Comment: `Range("1:1")` is row 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
colnum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Reference", _
         Worksheets("Reference").Rows(1), 0)
```

But remember you will get an error if no match is found. You will have to do proper error handling. For example

```
colnum = "Not Found"
On Error Resume Next
colnum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Reference", _ 
         Worksheets("Reference").Rows(1), 0)
On Error GoTo 0

Debug.Print colnum
```

The above will obviously will not handle Sheet name errors. For that you can use something like

```
     On Error GoTo Whoa

     colnum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Reference", _
              Worksheets("Reference").Rows(1), 0)

LetsContinue:
     Debug.Print colnum

     Exit Sub
Whoa:
     colnum = Err.Description
     Resume LetsContinue
```

You can also try `.Evaluate` for a one liner solution

`Application.Evaluate("=IFERROR(MATCH(""Reference"",Reference!1:1,0),""Not Found"")")`

**PS**: BTW I am slightly biased towards `.Find` :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a try on following sub.

```
Sub FindHeader()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range

    Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Define your desired sheet
    Set Rng = sht.Cells.Find("Reference") 'Find your desired value/text

        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then 'If found then do operation
            MsgBox Rng.Column 'You can do other actions here instead of messagebox
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If

    Set sht = Nothing 'Clear memory
    Set Rng = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah I prefer `.Find` too but remember that `.Find` uses the last setting. You may want to specify all the relevant parameters. For example`Set Rng = sht.Rows(1).Find(What:="Reference", LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)` ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thank for advise. Will remember.

Answer (score -2):

complete VBA noob here, but you might have misspelled 'column'? you wrote 'colnum'
Please disregard if this has absolutely nothing to do with it

Comment: While that is a great observation, in the given context, the output of the method would just be assigned to a variable colnum, or they may actually be trying to find a Column Number and that is why the variable is named colnum.